# Controlling column widths with Format-Table

Tags: powershell, formatting, formattable

I am trying to get the last reboot time of some PCs from a list. When I use

```
foreach ($pc in $pclist) {
  Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $pc |
    select csname, lastbootuptime 
}
```

The output comes as following.

```
csname       lastbootuptime
------       --------------
CONFA7-L1-1A 7/15/2016 9:55:16 AM
CONFA7-L1-1F 5/31/2016 8:51:46 AM
CONFA7-L1-1G 6/18/2016 11:09:15 AM
CONFA7-L1... 6/26/2016 5:31:31 PM
CONFA7-L3... 7/24/2016 3:48:43 PM
```

Which is neat, but if the PC name is long, I am unable to see the full name. 
So I pipelined `Format-Table`:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $pc |
  select csname, lastbootuptime |
  Format-Table  -HideTableHeaders
```

And this is what I get:

```
CONFA7-L1-1A 7/15/2016 9:55:16 AM



CONFA7-L1-1E 7/21/2016 12:58:16 PM



CONFA7-L1-1F 5/31/2016 8:51:46 AM
```

There are two problems here.

1. There is no heading. If I remove `-HideTableHeaders` there will be heading for every output which is not required.
2. There is a lot of white spaces in between.

Basically I just need to get an output similar to the first one, but without truncating the full names. How can I fix these?

Comment: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $pclist | Format-Table csname, lastbootuptime -AutoSize`

Comment: `-AutoSize` being key.

Comment: Thanks it works, but there is a small problem. It is not printing the order my list has. I mean I set it it ascending order, but the output is jumbled.

Comment: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $pclist| Sort-Object csname  -Ascending | Format-Table csname, lastbootuptime -AutoSize `. Am I right here? Because I get the following error. `Sort-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Ascending'.`

Comment: My bad. `Sort-Object` only has a parameter `-Descending`. Ascending order is the default, so just omit the parameter.

Comment: Cool !! Thank you very much. How do  I mark it as solved since this is just comment ?

Comment: And just to know, why I dont need to put this command in a  loop ?

Comment: *>why I dont need to put this command in a loop* Because `Get-CimInstance` already support of examine multiple computers at once. And since it do that in parallel, that makes results to go out of order.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To summarize and complement the helpful comments made by [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) and [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers):

**tl;dr**

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $pclist |
  Sort-Object CSName |
    Format-Table CSName, LastBootUpTime -AutoSize
```

**`-AutoSize` is what ensures that the `CSName` (computer name) column is as wide as it needs to** be to show all values in full (unless these values themselves are too long to fit on a single line, in which case `-Wrap` must be used - see below).

`Get-CimInstance` takes an *array* of computer names, so there's no need for a loop; however, since the target computers are queried *in parallel*, the order of objects returned will typically *not* match the input order of computer names - this is rectified with the `Sort-Object CSName` call.

To **control the width of *individual columns***:

```
# Instead of a simple property name, 'prop1', pass a *hashtable*
# (@{ ... }`) with a 'width' entry to Format-Table
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ prop1='1234567890'; prop2='other' } |
       Format-Table -Property @{ e='prop1'; width = 5 }, prop2

prop1 prop2
----- -----
1234… other
```

<sup>Note: In *Windows PowerShell*, you'll see just `12...` as the truncated value, because it uses *3 individual `.` characters* to represent the truncation; in PowerShell [Core] 6+ this was improved to using a *single* character, `…` (HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS, [`U+2026`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026)).</sup>

Read on to learn **more about table formatting.**

---

At its core, your question is about **how to control the output column width of tabular output**, which applies to *any* cmdlet's output.

**Use the `Format-Table` cmdlet (directly) for tabular output, *not* `Select-Object`**: the purpose of `Select-Object` is to create *custom objects*, not to format output; if such objects (generally, instances of any type without predefined formatting views) happen to haven *4 or fewer properties*, they are by default formatted with `Format-Table` behind the scenes (but you don't get to apply options); otherwise, it is `Format-List` that is implicitly used. <sup>Thanks, [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral).</sup>

- **`Format-Table` invariably limits output lines to the *available screen width***, which means:

  - Columns may not get printed at all.
  - Especially the last column that is printed may have its values truncated, with the missing part indicated by `...` / `…` - though note that *all* printed columns *can* have truncated values, as explained below.
- **If you want to create *longer lines***, pipe `Format-Table`'s output to `| Out-File -Width <int>` or `| Out-String -Stream -Width <int>`; note that if you print the latter to the screen, lines will *wrap* (but the extra line breaks won't be part of the data).

  - *Caveat*: On *Windows PowerShell*, do NOT use `-Width ([int]::MaxValue)`, because table-formatted data for types with formatting data is unconditionally right-padded with spaces to the full width, which can consume inordinate amounts of memory / space in the output file and you may even run out of memory. In PowerShell *Core*, this has been fixed as of at least v6.1.
  - An alternative on *Windows* (does not work in PowerShell Core on *Unix*-like platforms) is to use `[console]::BufferWidth = <column-count>` to widen the *screen buffer* to allow longer lines that don't wrap, but require *horizontal scrolling*.
    Additionally, on Windows it only works in the regular console, not in the ISE.
- To **control *column widths*** - which indirectly determines how many columns will fit - use the following parameters:

  - **`-AutoSize`** ... tells `Format-Table` to **make columns as wide as necessary** to fit all data values, but note that this **can result in fewer (less typically: more) columns getting displayed**.
  - **`-Wrap`** ... makes **column values span multiple lines**, if needed, to avoid truncation; again, this can apply to *all* columns<sup>Thanks, [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42).</sup>, not just the last one, namely in case an automatically determined or fixed column width (specified via  a `width` entry, as shown next) happens to be exceeded by specific values.
  - To **specify *custom column widths***, pass a **hashtable with a `width` entry** as an argument - a so-called [calculated property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39861920/45375) to `Format-Table`'s `-Property` parameter; e.g., the following example limits the 1st output column to 5 characters:

    ```
      [pscustomobject] @{ prop1='1234567890'; prop2='other' } |
        Format-Table -Property @{ e='prop1'; width = 5 }, prop2
    ```

    - If truncation occurs, which is applied to the *end* of values by default, the truncation indicator `...` / `…` invariably takes up the *last 3* characters of the truncated value (in *Windows PowerShell*) / only the *last* character (in *PowerShell [Core] 6+*); in the example above, the `prop1` value renders as `12...` / `1234…` for a total of 5 chars.
    - To truncate the *start* of values instead, you must change the column to be *right*-aligned, with a `alignment = 'right'` entry (default is `'left'`, `'center'` is the 3rd option; both of these truncate the *end* of values).
    - If you want to retain *left* alignment while still truncating at the *start* of values, you'll have to use a custom expression in a script block (`{ ... }`) assigned to the `e` (`expression`) entry:

      ```
      [pscustomobject] @{ prop1='1234567890'; prop2='other' } |
        Format-Table -Property @{ 
            n='prop1'; e={ $_.prop1 -replace '^.+(.{4})$', '…$1'}; width = 5 
          }, prop2
      ```
    - Note: **Specifying at least one custom width means that you must explicitly enumerate *all* properties to output** in the `-Property` argument, even the ones that don't need custom widths.<sup>[1]</sup>
- **Caveats, as of PowerShell 7.1**:

  - A *bug* prevents custom widths from taking effect unless the *first* column (also) has one; additionally, it *never* takes effect in the *last* column - see [GitHub issue #14676](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14676).
  - As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out and demonstrates in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65925861/7571258), **if the *first* column is a calculated one that specifies a custom width, the remaining line width is *evenly distributed* among those remaining columns that do not themselves specify a column width**, irrespective of how wide the values in those columns actually are - **unless you also pass `-AutoSize`**. This unexpected behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #14677](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14677).

---

<sup>[1] As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, you can technically bypass this requirement *if all columns are to have the same custom width*, because passing a property-name string to the `e` (`Expression`) hashtable entry is interpreted as a *wildcard pattern*, so that string `'*'` matches *all* property names; e.g.:

`[pscustomobject] @{ a=1; b=2 } | Format-Table @{ e='*'; width=10 }`</sup>

Answer (score 19):

If you want trim data past a certain length and manually specify column widths, you can pass a `Width` property for each property attribute.

For example, if you wanted your data to look like this:

```
Column 1    Column 2      Column 3      Column 4
--------    --------      --------      --------
Data        Lorem ip...   Lorem ip...   Important data
```

Here's the basic `Format-Table` syntax, with a list of explicit properties:

```cs
$data | Format-Table -Property Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 -AutoSize
```

Instead of just passing in the property names, we can add some [additional metadata to `Property`](https://superuser.com/a/956308/180163):

```
$a = @{Expression={$_.Col1}; Label="Column 1"; Width=30}, 
     @{Expression={$_.Col2}; Label="Column 2"; Width=30}, 
     @{Expression={$_.Col3}; Label="Column 3"; Width=30}, 
     @{Expression={$_.Col4}; Label="Column 4"; Width=30}
$data | Format-Table -Property $a
```

**Note**: I realize this is covered at the bottom of mklement0's more complete answer, but if this is your use case and you're scrolling quickly, I hope this helps highlight this strategy at a high level

Comment: I upgraded a machine to powershell 5.1 and all of a sudden my columns weren't aligned in an email report. Adding your `Width=x` argument in the hash table re-aligned everything.

Comment: Making this info more discoverable makes perfect sense, given the title of the question; I've since added this technique to the top of my answer too, but your answer still offers something additional: it shows how to use the calculated property hashtable to also _rename_ the output column.