# Print a txt-file containing tab characters using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, printing, xps

I'm trying to write a script in Powershell to automatically print the contents of a text file. However, my tab characters are removed when printing making the final output hard to read.

I've provided an MWE to illustrate the issue.

Contents of MWE.txt (encoded in ANSI; a `→` represents a tab character):

```
FOO→1,23→4,56
```

My powershell script:

```
$fname = "C:\MWE.txt"
Get-Content $fname | Out-Printer -name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
```

I'm using the XPS writer to avoid wasting paper, but in the end this will be changed to a real printer. The output on real paper is identical, I've ruled that out too.

Problem is that the in the print output, the tab characters are just erased, yielding:

```
FOO1,234,56
```

However, If I instead change the `Out-Printer` to `Out-String`, the console displays the file contents correctly. What on earth am I doing wrong? The file displays correctly with tabs in both notepad and notepad++, and I've tried UTF-8 encoding as well.

### Edit 2018-07-12 10:20

Content structure of the file I'm trying to print, which is automatically generated by a system and put on a web server for which I have no access. For clarity, I've used `→` to denote the tab character and `·` to denote a space:

```
MWE·-·TestFile·:·

0)→Time
1)→Temperature·1
2)→Humidity
3)→Pressure·A-B
4)→Pressure·A-C
5)→Pressure·D-C

0)···················→1)→2)→3)→4)→5)→
2018-07-04 12:00:00→22,03→5,34→18,93→23,10→10,10
2018-07-04 13:00:00→21,99→5,22→18,75→23,56→10,00
2018-07-04 14:00:00→21,99→5,17→18,55→23,54→10,15
2018-07-04 15:00:00→22,03→5,25→18,73→23,41→8,33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no *explanation* - the symptom sounds like a [bug](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/34863562-out-printer-appears-to-mishandle-tab-characters) (that also affects the `Microsoft Print To PDF` printer) and it seems to be specific to *tab* characters, whereas *spaces* work fine.

However, I can offer a **workaround** - assuming that the end goal is to create *aligned* output columns and that it isn't necessary to use *tabs* specifically to achieve that:

```
Get-Content "C:\MWE.txt" | ForEach-Object {
  # Construct a custom object whose properties contain the
  # tab-separated tokens on the input line.
  $obj = New-Object PSCustomObject; $i = 0
  foreach ($val in $_ -split "`t") {
    Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName ('col' + ++$i) -NotePropertyValue $val 
  }
  $obj
} | Format-Table -Property (1..6 | % { 'col' + $_ }) -HideTableHeaders | 
      Out-Printer -Name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
```

- The `ForEach-Object` script block splits each input line into tokens by tabs and constructs a custom object with properties containing the individual tokens.
- `Format-Table` creates table output with columns that use *spaces* for alignment; `-HideTableHeaders` suppresses output of a table header, which would normally display the (autogenerated) property names.

  - Note that since the input has lines with *varying* column counts, `-FormatTable` has to be instructed explicitly as to which columns to display, which is what `(1..6 | % { 'col' + $_ })` does: it creates an array of all the auto-generated column names based on the assumption that *at most* 6 columns can be present, which is true of your sample input - adjust that number as needed. (To be safe, you may also specify a higher number, say, `20`, but that will slow processing down.
- Piping `Format-Table`'s output to `Out-Printer -Name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"` seems to result in the desired tabular output with aligned columns.

  - If column values end up getting *truncated* (indicated by `...`), you need to tweak the `Format-Table` call, such as with custom column widths - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576389/45375) of mine.

---

Running this against your sample input yields the following 6-column layout in the console, and the output XPS document renders similarly:

```
MWE·-·TestFile·:·                                                                                                                                                                   

0)                    Time                                                                                                                                                          
1)                    Temperature·1                                                                                                                                                 
2)                    Humidity                                                                                                                                                      
3)                    Pressure·A-B                                                                                                                                                  
4)                    Pressure·A-C                                                                                                                                                  
5)                    Pressure·D-C                                                                                                                                                  

0)··················· 1)            2)   3)    4)    5)                                                                                                                             
2018-07-04 12:00:00   22,03         5,34 18,93 23,10 10,10                                                                                                                          
2018-07-04 13:00:00   21,99         5,22 18,75 23,56 10,00                                                                                                                          
2018-07-04 14:00:00   21,99         5,17 18,55 23,54 10,15                                                                                                                          
2018-07-04 15:00:00   22,03         5,25 18,73 23,41 8,33
```

Comment: @mkelemnt0: Thanks! I'll consider this the accepted answer as it provides a nice workaround for the issue. However, there is a caveat when the header explanations (top rows which keys the column numbers to names) are considerably long (and using the `-AutoSize` option to `Format-Table`). The reason is that the tabular data do not actually start from row one, but is processed as such. I do not deem it necessary to put more effort into this, as I hope the supposed bug in `Out-Printer` would be fixed in coming versions. - Again, thanks for all help!

Comment: @noffe: Thanks, and good point about needing to handle the legend differently. On a side note, there is an actual bug in `Format-Table` related to `-AutoSize`: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7309

Comment: @noffe: Also, I've reported the original bug (tabs getting stripped) here: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/34863562-out-printer-appears-to-mishandle-tab-characters

Answer (score 2):

You're close, and you stumbled onto a workaround yourself - the use of `Out-String`. You can add `Out-String` to the pipeline before sending the content to the printer:

```
Get-Content $fname | Out-String | Out-Printer -Name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
```

If the above isn't working for you you can try processing the tab character yourself:

```
( Get-Content $fname -Raw ).Split( "`t" ) -Join "`t"
```

If that displays the output as you're expecting, you can pipe that to `Out-Printer` (`Out-String` isn't necessary because `-Join` concatenates into a string):

```
( Get-Content $fname -Raw ).Split( "`t" ) -Join "`t" |
  Out-Printer -Name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
```

However, this seems like it may be a bug with `Out-Printer`, as comments and other answers have yielded varying success rates. The workarounds above are known to work on at least `Windows 10.0.15063.0` (the version I'm currently running and tested with), but may have stopped working in later versions.

You may try converting the tabs to spaces as a workaround:

```
# This is set to 5 spaces here, but can be any number of
# spaces you want to represent a tab character
$replaceTabString = "     "
( Get-Content $fname -Raw ).Replace( "`t", $replaceTabString ) |
  Out-Printer -Name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
```

Comment: Doesn't `Get-Content` just return an array of strings by default?

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. I haven't tried piping `Out-String` per se, but I actually tried piping through the `echo` function.

Comment: I literally just tested this and it solves the missing `tab` problem in the generated xps document.

Comment: Try `Get-Content $fname -Raw  | Out-Printer -name "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"`. p.s. Are you sure the encoding is ANSI? `Get-Content` does have a `-Encoding` switch. You could try different encodings if you still don't see the tabs.

Comment: I added an alternative method to process the tabs yourself

Comment: @Theo I actually tried adding `-Raw` to `Get-Content`first and it yielded the same result, removal of the tabs when sent to `Out-Printer`.

Comment: My own experiments tell me that the problem is not that the tabs don't _reach_ the printer - `Get-Content` does output them -  it's that the printer _removes_ them. The only thing `Out-String` does is to output the file content as a _single_ string (similar to `Get-Content -Raw`), but with an extra trailing newline. In short, your workarounds are ineffective, at least with the Microsoft XPS Document Writer printer that comes with Windows 10 Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.492)

Comment: Well, I was able to reproduce the original issue on Windows 10.0.15063.0 - piping the contents of the text file to `Out-Printer` (I ensured tabs were used) yielded the tabs stripped from the XPS document. First piping the file to `Out-String`, or the workaround by splitting on and re-adding the tabs fixed the issue on my system.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, this seems to be a bug with `Out-Printer` (OP stated the issue persists when printing to a real printer), where my workarounds above stopped working on the latest version of Windows 10, but is valid on earlier builds.

Comment: I've tried all of the above but with no success. Of course, replacing the tab characters with spaces works as long as all columns are identical in character width (which is not true in my case), otherwise the output will be misaligned which is not an option. However, this fortifies the belief that there is a bug in `Out-Printer` regarding the tab chacacter.

Comment: I would recommend you file an issue on the [Github project](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).