# How to stop Invoke-Sqlcmd from truncating query

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd, invoke-sqlcmd

One of our tables has very very long records in a particular column.
These queries are used infrequently, but are necessary.

I have been using sqlcmd utility in bash like so:

```sql
-- getfile.sql

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Disable message for next USE command
:setvar SQLCMDERRORLEVEL 1
USE myDb;
SELECT myField
FROM myTable 
GO

-- Reenable
:setvar SQLCMDERRORLEVEL 0
```

```sh
# getfile.sh

sqlcmd \
    -S $server \
    -U $username \
    -P $password \
    -y 0 \
    -I getfile.sql > filename.txt
```

`-y 0` being the trick here that allows me to get my text without it being truncated.

So now I need to convert this to PowerShell.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd `
    -ServerInstance $server `
    -Username $username `
    -Password $password `
    -InputFile 'get_clientfile.sql' `
    -Variable $StringArray `
    | Out-File 'filename.txt'
```

But sadly my output is limited to:

```
myField
-----------------
BEGIN…
```

I also tried using `MaxCharLength` and `MaxBinaryLength` to no avail.

So far I have not discovered a way to prevent it from truncating output.

Also notice it is not respecting my sqlcmd commands like `:setvar`.  One way around this, what `-y` really does (I think) might be to set the `SQLCMDMAXVARTYPEWIDTH` to 0.  But I can't find a way to set variables like this when using `Invoke-SqlCmd`.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I hope the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576389/45375) provides a solution; let us know if not.

Comment: I was able to do it by adding this to my query `| Format-Table -Wrap -HideTableHeaders`.  Thanks!