# Powershell adjust the format table width

Tags: powershell, formatting

This is the script

```
get-childitem D:\media\*.mkv -recurse | Select-Object -Property name,  @{n='Resolution';expression={mediainfo $_.FullName --inform="Video;%Width%x%Height%"}}
```

and the output is

```
Name                      Resolution
----                      ----------
Video File -Copy (2).mkv 1920x1080 
Video File -Copy (3).mkv 1920x1080 
Video File -Copy (4).mkv 1920x1080 
Video File -Copy (5).mkv 1920x1080 
Video File -Copy (6).mkv 1920x1080 
Video File -Copy (7).mkv 1920x1080 
Video File -Copy.mkv     1920x1080 
Video File.mkv           1920x1080
```

but if file name character is big, the resolution column info get missing. name column info gets overlapping.

i read this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.2

but i am not sure how to implement the property width or auto size.

Comment: Try explicitly piping to `Format-Table -AutoSize` - it'll take a little longer before it starts rendering the output (because it's waiting for all the input), but then it'll adjust the column widths according to the longest value

Comment: @Mathias, that would predictably drop the `Resolution` column if at least one name is wider than the display, which is undesired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) to limit the width of the `Name` column; e.g.:

```sh
... | Format-Table @{ Name='Name'; Expression = 'Name'; Width = 60 }, Resolution
```

Longer values are then truncated with `...` / `…` in Windows PowerShell / PowerShell (Core) 7+. You may add `-Wrap` to show them in full, spread across as many lines as needed.

The alternative - which won't render nicely on screen - is to pipe to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) and use its `-Width` parameter with a terminal-column count large enough to accommodate all table columns:

```sh
... | Out-String -Width 300
```

Note: With your output objects, `Format-Table` formatting is *implied* (they have 4 or fewer properties), which is why there's no explicit call to it above.

As an aside:

- `Format-Table -Autosize` does *not* help, as it doesn't ensure that all columns are shown - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576389/45375) for more information.

---

Sample code:

```sh
[pscustomobject] @{
  Name = 'x' * 80 + 'y'
  Resolution = '1920x1080'
},
[pscustomobject] @{
  Name = 'x' * 280 + 'z'
  Resolution = '2560x1600'
} |
  Format-Table -Wrap @{ Name='Name'; Expression = 'Name'; Width = 60 }, Resolution
```

Output:

```
Name                                                         Resolution
----                                                         ----------
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 1920x1080
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 2560x1600
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxz
```