# Get a table of Azure AD B2C users with custom attributes

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-powershell

I need to get in my terminal a table that lists all users together with certain attributes.
I use powershell that was set up using commands `Install-Module AzureAD` and  `Connect-AzureAD -Tenant "<mydirectory>.onmicrosoft.com"`.

When I inquiry a single user, I get this:

```
О»  Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId dacbdd03-... | Select -ExpandProperty ExtensionProperty

Key                                                   Value
---                                                   -----
odata.metadata                                        https://graph.windows.net/ee26ec1a.../$metadata#directoryObjects/@Element
odata.type                                            Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
createdDateTime                                       31.01.2023 19:57:55
employeeId
onPremisesDistinguishedName
userIdentities                                        []
extension_<largenumber>_customerId                    48f6eadf-...
```

I need now to output a table of all users, so I list its `objectId`, `extension_<largenumber>_customerId` and also an email field. Note that I have millions of users (result should be dumped in a file).

Answer (score 1):

You can review all properties to filter by using an example ObjectID (such as your own) by running the following:

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId example@contoso.com | select *
```

After you know what filters you'd like, you'll use a few additional flags:

- `-all $true` to run against all users
- `> results.csv` to dump to a csv file
- `Format-Table -AutoSize` to force table output, if you decide to include more than five properties of an AzureADUser

Try using something like this as your starting point.

```
Get-AzureADUser -all $true | select ObjectID, mail, extension_<largenumber>_customerId  | Format-Table -AutoSize > C:\output\results.csv
```

Name the output file and location as you'd like.

You should also consider narrowing down your search as you're running against a million users. Consider narrowing down your search definition. Perhaps you can search for only users in a particular email domain, company, or department?

I'm not sure of any negligible impact this script could have querying against a million user records. Perhaps someone with more experience could comment.

Comment: I also found very thorough answer about the formatting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38554966/controlling-column-widths-with-format-table.

Comment: I have however an issue, that when I do `Get-AzureADUser -Top 1 | select ObjectID, SignInNames, ExtensionProperty  |  Out-String -Stream -Width 10000`
I still get truncated output as the two latter are complex fields. I would need to avoid truncation or to print their sub-fields of interest. Could you suggest how to do so?

I get now:
`000008f7-... {class SignInName {...            {[odata.type, Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User], [createdDateTime, 17.08.2021 7:21:03], [employeeId, ], [onPremisesDistinguishedName, ]...}`