# How to increase spacing between columns in txt file using Powershell commands?

Tags: powershell, format, text-files

I want to increase the spacing between the columns in my text file, as the columns are too close together and it is not easy to read the data.

A section of how my text file looks like now:

[image]

This is my powershell code:

```
$output = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'jared.h'" -Properties whenChanged,DistinguishedName | Select SamAccountName,Enabled,whenChanged,DistinguishedName

$output | Format-Table * | Out-File -FilePath C:\output.txt -Width 5000
```

What do I need to change to get an output that looks like this?

[image]

I am unable to use Format-Table -AutoSize as I need to show all 13 columns in the text file.

I have also tried adding a property width to the format-table:

```
$output | Format-Table -Property @{ e='SamAccountName,Enabled,whenChanged'; width = 1000 } | Out-File -FilePath C:\output.txt -Width 5000 Format-Table
```

But it removes all the data, and takes away any spacing between the headers and replaces them with a comma:

```
SamAccountName,Enabled,whenChanged 
----------------------------------
```

Comment: you should really be using `Export-Csv` and not be using `Format-Table` at all for exporting your data. How does exporting this object that looks like a table help you in any way? You can't sort it, you can't filter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to define each column with an `expression` and set the related `width` where it is allowed to use a property name (`string`) instead of the expression (see: [GitHub issue #14676](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14676))

```
…  |Format-Table @{e='SamAccountName';width=30}, @{e='Enabled';width=20}
```

See [calculated properties/format-list](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties#format-list)

With regards to your comment:

> *Thanks. But for this command, I would have to customize the width of each column, then try out many different widths to try and get the same amount of spacing/distance between each columns. Is there an easier way to get equal spacing between the columns*

I am afraid that the `Format-Table` cmdlet isn't as sophisticated as [WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/desktop/winforms) or [Windows Presentation Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/overview/)  and doesn't have something like a `-stretch` parameter. Besides it is quiet hard to determine how the data in the column is divided especially in a active pipeline and where the data could even exceed the available column width as in the `DistinguishedName` column of your own example.

Anyways, I see two possible workarounds:

#### Take advantage of a quirk

*if the first column is a calculated one that specifies a custom width, the remaining line width is evenly distributed among those remaining columns that do not themselves specify a column width*  which is also described in [**@mklement0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)'s helpful answer for [Controlling column widths with Format-Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38576389/1701026):

```
… |Format-Table @{e='SamAccountName'; w=15},Enabled,whenChanged,DistinguishedName -Wrap |
    out-String -Width 90

SamAccountName                   Enabled whenChanged              DistinguishedName
--------------                   ------- -----------              -----------------
iRon7                              False 5/10/2023 9:05:23 AM     CN=iRon7,OU=Test,OU=User
                                                                  s,DC=Consoto,DC=com
```

Disadvantage: it will not change the spacing between a Right - and Left aligned columns (as between `Enabled` and `whenChanged`).

#### Use a spacer

Create an empty column with a "white" header name:

```
$Spacer = @{n=' '; e=' '}

… |Format-Table SamAccountName,$Spacer,Enabled,$Spacer,whenChanged,$Spacer,DistinguishedName

SamAccountName   Enabled   whenChanged            DistinguishedName
-------------- - ------- - -----------          - -----------------
iRon7              False   5/10/2023 9:05:23 AM   CN=iRon7,OU=Test,OU=Users,DC=Consoto,DC=com
```

Disadvantage: this places extra dashes (`-`) on the ruler.

Comment: Thanks. But for this command, I would have to customise the width of each column, then try out many different widths to try and get the same amount of spacing/distance between each columns. Is there an easier way to get equal spacing between the columns?